# Update ListFragment in Tab Layout when Activity finishes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listfragment

In my app i have a tab layout (4 total), each tab contain a ListFragment managed by a ViewPagerAdapter, what i want to do is update the content of one of these ListFragment when an activity (called with a button in the Action bar) finishes, and possibly set the focus on the right Tab.

I've searched for a solution and i have found this one : [update ListFragment when Activity finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843454/update-listfragment-when-activity-finishes) , but seems doesn't works in my case.

For start the activity (the one for adding an user to display in the list) in the MainActivity i've used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateUser.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
```

At the end of the CreateUser activity i've set:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

And in the ListFragment class:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
        ((BaseAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But when the activity finishes nothing happens because onActivityResult is never called. How can i do?

EDIT : Added class for best understanding

**CreateUser.java**

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {

  //The user creation process is done inside class ProcessCreateUser
  //that extend AsycTask

  private class ProcessCreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    //...
    //onPreExecute, doInBackground
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        super.onPostExecute();

        //db op...

        //at this point the db is updated with the new user and close the activity

        finish();
    }
  }

  public void onDestroy(){
        Tab3.updateFragmentList();
  }
}
```

**Tab3.java** (ListFragment class)

```
public class Tab3 extends ListFragment implements Observer
{
    //in onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) i get the data from the db and set the adapter

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {

    }

    public static void updateFragmentList() {
       //problem: i can't get the adapter from a static function
       //but this must be static for be called from CreateUser
       ((BaseAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it (without Observer), i've moved the onActivityResult method from ListFragment to MainActivity, in the ListFragment i've added a simple public void updateView() method for all the update jobs of the list, and i've added the following method into the ViewPagerAdapter for call the updateView() method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Tab3) {
        ((Tab3) object).updateView();
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Observer pattern. For example:

```
public interface Observer {
  public void updateFragmentList();
}

public class YourFragment extends Fragment implement Observer {
  public void updateFragmentList() {
    // You do some magic code here, such as:
    // Update your data for each FragmentList
  }
}

public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  private ArrayList<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
  public void onCreate() {
     // Here you add all FragmentList to observers
  }

  public void onDestroy(){ 
     for(Observer ob in observers) {
        ob.updateFragmentList();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, if i've understood well, In the class CreateUser, where i add an user into the database (to show it in the ListFragment) i need to extend Observable and in the ListFragment class i need to implement Observer, so i can observe changing in the CreateUser class and call the update method, right? The problem is that i already extend AppCompatActivity in CreateUser, so i can't call setChanged() and notifyObservers()..

Comment: I think we also could implement it. Well, as you know our ListFragment class will override function updateFragmentList(Data newData) { add newData to arraylist; notify data change;}. Beside, your class CreateUser will travel its observers list and call ob.updateFragmentList(newData). Hope it will usefull.

Comment: See my edited post, i've added the classes for best understanding. If i call updateFragmentList() from CreateUser class the method must be Static, and in this condition i can't get the Adapter for update the View. Sorry but i'm new in android programming so i'm not very good.. can you give me an example based on my Classes? Thank you @duynt.

Comment: You could take a look at this demo project https://github.com/nguyentrungduy/Observer-pattern . However after think again, in my opinion you should read database & update ListFragment inside its onResume() function. It's better for structure.